# NSFetchedResultsController with predicate ignores changes merged from different NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I am presenting table view contents using `NSFetchedResultsController` which has a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"visible == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

On background thread using separate `NSManagedObjectContext` I update few of the entities and change theirs `visible` value from `NO` to `YES`. Save, merge changes in main thread's `NSManagedObjectContext`. But `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchedObjects` doesn't change. Also controller doesn't call `-controller:didChangeObject:...` on delegate. If entities are updated on main thread in identical manner (my test app calls the same method), everything works as expected.

Also Notification's `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` contains those objects.

Currently the only solutions I've found is to call for each of `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` entities:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... // main thread context
[context existingObjectWithID:[object objectID] error:nil]
```

This issue is only with **updated** objects which previously didn't match the predicate.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Isn't it a bug of Core Data? I think we should fire bug report to Apple. I just did one.

Comment: Bug?  If so any progress?

Comment: This bug is finally fixed in iOS 10: https://twitter.com/an0/status/750413478620491776

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Turns out main `NSManagedObjectContext` didn' t event fire `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` for updated objects because it is not done for faulted objects.

Generic fix (or keep a track of object IDs that needs this treatment):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
for(NSManagedObject *object in [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
  [[context objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
}

[context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

From [NSManagedObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willAccessValueForKey:):

> You can invoke this method with the
>   key value of nil to ensure that  a
>   fault has been fired, as illustrated
>   by the following example.

Comment: This saved me so much time. I cannot upvote this enough. Thank you.

Comment: Wow same for me. Been wasting hours on this!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to do this with different settings on the `NSFetchRequest`? I tried specifying `relationshipsForPrefetching` and -[NSFetchRequest setReturnsObjectAsFaults:NO]`, but neither worked.

Comment: Also, this didn't work for me. I have basically the exact same scenario you do.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing the merge on the background thread.  The merge of changes needs to be done on the main/UI thread for the events to fire properly.  This is moot though if you are using parent/child MOCs as they handle these notifications internally.

Comment: Nope, all of my changes and merges happen on the main thread. I'll create a sample project tomorrow with a radar.

Comment: Nevermind. I swear this didn't work on my project the first time I tried it, but I just tried it again, and it worked. Sorry.

Comment: Using MagicalRecord, and I seem to be running into the same problem.  However the fix above did not work for me.  I do have my FRC on a background context (thread) and I am not seeing changes.

Comment: @lostintranslation Did you find solution with MagicalRecord?

Comment: This was in fact a bug that Apple fixed a few years ago. The question isn't relevant anymore (2016 onwards).

Answer (score 1):

You have to call *processPendingChanges* on your Background-NSManagedObjectContext after you merged the changes from an other NSManagedObjectContext.

See CoreData Programming Guide:

> Note that the change notification is sent in NSManagedObjectContext’s
>   processPendingChanges method. The main thread is tied into the event
>   cycle for the application so that processPendingChanges is invoked
>   automatically after every user event on contexts owned by the main
>   thread. This is not the case for background threads—when the method is
>   invoked depends on both the platform and the release version, so you
>   should not rely on particular timing. If the secondary context is not
>   on the main thread, you should call processPendingChanges yourself at
>   appropriate junctures.

Comment: Are you sure this would fix the issue above? I don't think the NSFetchedResults controller is listening for change notifications from the *background* context.

Comment: `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` performs (almost) the same process as `processPendingChanges`, and posts the appropriate notification.

Comment: It's not that `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` performs the same process as `processPendingChanges`, it's the fact that `processPendingChanges` gets called as part of the merge. `processPendingChanges` is guaranteed to be called by the end of each runloop (at least on macOS) or each time a context is saved. It also gets called as part of merge.