# NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods not being called with compound predicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSFetchedResultsController with predicate ignores changes merged from different NSManagedObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923826/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-predicate-ignores-changes-merged-from-different)

I am using a NSFetchedResultsController to control the updating of a grid view I am using.  I am setting up a compound predicate where there is a boolean property that I'm checking for NO and then ALSO checking to see if there are any of the relationship entity.

In a background thread, I use a separate MOC to save, and this works no problem.  With the predicate only set to the selected part, my delegate methods get called.  If I add the relationship part of the predicate, my delegate never gets called.

Is this a limitation of the NSFetchedResultsController?  Can it not check children entities?

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
    NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tab"];
    //Problematic line here.
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(selected == NO) && (modules.@count > 0)"];
    [req setPredicate:pred];
    [req setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
    NSFetchedResultsController *fc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    [fc setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Something to add to this.  If I do the update in the background, and the delegate doesn't get called.  I can close the app, and then the initial load of the fetch controller shows the item in the grid!

Comment: And of course, I find the answer to this as soon as I post. Sigh.  This fixed my problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923826/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-predicate-ignores-changes-merged-from-different?rq=1