# How to be sure NSFetchedResultsController is notified after background thread save with MagicalRecord 3.0

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using MagicalRecord 3.0 with the `ClassicWithBackgroundCoordinatorSQLiteMagicalRecordStack` stack and a NSFetchedResultsController. Having an issue where the NSFetchedResultsController is not being updated after Magical Record saves new relevant data using a background thread (via `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:]`).

The stack is initialized thusly:

```
    MagicalRecordStack *stack = [[ClassicWithBackgroundCoordinatorSQLiteMagicalRecordStack alloc] initWithStoreNamed:@"Mailstrom.sqlite"];
    [MagicalRecordStack setDefaultStack:stack];
```

The NSFetchedResultsController is initialized as follows:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSClassFromString(_entityName)
                               MR_requestAllSortedBy:_weightProperty
                               ascending:NO
                               withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K>%d", _weightProperty, 0]];

    request.sortDescriptors = @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:_weightProperty ascending:NO] ];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                     initWithFetchRequest:request
                                     managedObjectContext:[[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] context]
                                     sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                     cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [_fetchedResultsController MR_performFetch];
```

Occasionally saves made via `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:]` are picked up, but most often, a `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` is sent for the background context only, and the FRC just sits there:

`====>> context will save: saveWithBlock:completion: on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***`

The FRC is never notified in this case and its delegate's `controllerWillUpdateContent` is never fired.

I feel like this could be a simple issue -- better call Saul! ;) Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your saves eventually get to the default context, then your fetched results controller will eventually reload with the most up to date information. It might be that the ClassicWithBackgroundCoordinatorMagicalRecordStack is not properly set up to save through that stack's 'context' property.

Comment: Thanks. If I force a MR_perform_fetch on the FRC (in, say, viewWillAppear) then the changes are picked up, so the updates are getting to the default context. They're just not being picked up right away by the FRC. Any suggestions on what I might try?

Comment: I think my issue may be this (failure to update NSFetchedResultsController that has a predicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923826/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-predicate-ignores-changes-merged-from-different

Answers suggest that firing `[object willAccessValueForKey:nil]` will help, but I'm unclear if that should be done in the background context (prior to merge) or if I need to do it on the default context somehow. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I figured this out (I think). The deal is that when values are updated in the background PSC the main context needs to be poked in order to see the object changes. The easiest way to do that is to look up the values in the main object store by URI->ObjectID->Object and run `[willAccessValueForKey:nil]` on them, inside of the [MagicalRecord save] block. This might be something to consider adding support for in MR, as it seems like a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

When values are updated in the background PSC the main context needs to be poked in order to see the object changes. The easiest way to do that is to look up the values in the main object store by URI->ObjectID->Object and run [willAccessValueForKey:nil] on them, inside of the [MagicalRecord save] block. This way, when the changes are merged into the main context, they will know that they have been faulted, even if the updates from the background PSC are just changes.

Comment: Is this still the case?  I seem to be running into something very similar, but calling [willAccessValueForKey:nil] is not sending the change notification to my FRC.